# Flutter: components overlap the phone's top bar

Tags: flutter

Why is the screen overlapping with the phone's topbar? Is it because of the emulator or did I miss something?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `SafeArea` ,The `SafeArea` widget is used to ensure that the content of your app is visible and not obscured by device-specific elements such as the status bar, navigation bar, or any notches or cutouts on the screen.

The `SafeArea` widget **is used to provide a padding around the content of your app**, ensuring that it is visible and not hidden by any of the device-specific elements. This is particularly important on devices with notches or cutouts, where the content of your app might be obscured by the device hardware.

Here's an example of how you might use the `SafeArea` widget in your code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Screen'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Hello, World!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, the `SafeArea` widget ensures that the text "Hello, World!" is not hidden by any device-specific elements, such as the status bar or navigation bar. The `SafeArea` **widget adds padding to the top and bottom of the content**, ensuring that it is visible and not obscured by any hardware.

Answer (score 1):

you must warp your scafold with `SafeArea` Widget